# relationship zone

Tags: single-word-requests, interpersonal-relations

I'm looking for a phrase to describe a certain relationship similar to "friend zone". The relationship is where you can't treat a person one way because you are so connected it might cause problems in another area of life.

An example would be. I can't date Jane since we work together. She is in my ----- zone.

Comment: Does **friend zone** not imply that you *can't get any* because you guys are just friends? Wouldn't you mean something more like 'group of friends'?

Comment: She is in my *co-worker* zone. Because otherwise, she's in my *fraternization forbidden* zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She is in my *conflict* zone. This is related to the concept *[conflict of interest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflict+of+interest)*.

> a conflict between the private interests and the official responsibilities of a person in a position of trust [*Merriam-Webster*]

Answer (score 0):

A better word choice than *zone* would be **circle** where the definition includes

> a group of people who are connected by family, work, or society, or who share an interest ([Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/circle))

The you can express your point in a more recognizable way:

> I can't date Jane since we work together. She is in my **circle of coworkers (or business associates)**.

*Circle of friends* is a common expression.

If you use [Google+](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/circles/), you know how they have adapted this *circle* expression for you to organizes however many group relationships you might have.

[image: Google+ Circles]

Comment: That’s the marvelous thing about a circus: everybody gets a ringside seat.

Comment: I'm looking for a word that categorises the relationship. Maybe the reason is she is your boss. That doesn't mean that relationship holds for your other co-workers.

Answer (score 0):

How about just **work**?

It's common to talk of *work-life separation*. Life (short for *lifestyle* including friends, family, health, pleasure, leisure) and work (career and ambition) can have their own *zones*.